# Libgdx Parse Error

Tags: libgdx

I'm working on a LibGdx project, Demo and copied some code from another LibGDX project folder, MarioBros.
Now, after running the code, the program throws an error saying
ParseError, cannot parse file MarioBros/core/assets/untitled.tsx

Any fix guys? Why is my Demo project finding files in another project folder?

Comment: Maybe untitled.tmx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to access files that aren't in your project directory.

In the code that you copy and pasted you seem to be using a tsx file somewhere.

Also, the code is not finding files in another project folder. It is just trying to find them but can't, hence, the error.

You can either

- Delete the lines of code that use these files that you are no longer using.
- Add in the file into your directory so it can be used.

I hope this helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: I added the file. No use.

Comment: The problem was solved. I had to restart IntelliJ :/

Comment: Brilliant! Glad you got it fixed!